# rename fragment class which is referenced in the xml

Tags: android, android-fragments

I love fragments - BUT renaming the classes is a real pain if the fragment class is referenced in an xml like this:

```
<fragment
 android:id="@+id/listFragment"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.pkg1.Screens.MyFragmentClass" >
```

Now when renaming MyFragmentClass with its java file renames only JAVA files - all the xml referenced stay the same.

Is there a "secret" way to rename so that also the xml references get updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not particularly secret, but you could use Eclipse to do a File Search, use a file name pattern of *.xml, and replace "class="com.pkg1.Screens.MyFragmentClass"" with whatever you're renaming it to...?

Comment: yes, that is possible, but would be nice to rename the class AND the references in xml at the same time if possible

Comment: thanks for that - but after reading about it I am afraid that it will be too slow, since everywhere it says that its not as fast as Eclipse. My project is not huge, but about 500k lines or so and I love Eclipse for the speed. By the way on iPhone I have to wait about 1.5-2 hours while Eclipse finishes it in max 30secs...